# Плагин для подтягивания классов из html в vscode

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code

Есть ли такие плагины, чтобы у меня когда пишу в js файле, подтягивались названия классов из html файла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот спустя несколько часов поиска нашел https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TabNine.tabnine-vscode